# Only get information in increments for Rails loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, loops

Given the code below:

```
var photos = [
<% current_app_user.photos.each do |photo| %>
{ url: "<%= photo.thumbnail_uri(400, 189) %>", title: "<%= truncate(photo.name, 65) %>", path :"<%= photo_path(photo) %>" },
<% end %>
];
```

How would I modify it to only pull 10 photos at a time?

Initially, I'd like to generate 10, then with the click of a button append 10 more and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in a controller, not in your view, but inside a controller you should do it like this:

```
@photos = current_app_user.photos.all(:limit => 10).map do |p| 
  { :url => p.thumbnail_uri(400, 189),
    :title => p.name,
    :path => photo_path(p) }
end
```

And in your view:

```
var photos = <%= @photos.to_json %>;
```

No code in your view other than what's strictly necessary :)

Comment: this is working great. Thanks so much. If I wanted to grab the next 10 and append it to var photos, how would I do that with the click of a button?

Comment: You would have to do an ajax call and you would also have to paginate these results using a gem like will_paginate or kaminari.

Comment: damn, ok.  the json is actually being used by jcarousel so can't really use will_paginate.  I was hoping to bypass will_paginate by doing an AJAX call on the next button click event. Any ideas? Your help is much appreciated.  I've been looking at this for too long.

Comment: you can't do an ajax call to get the next 10 items if you don't know at what page you are, hence the need to use a gem like will_paginate.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 10 results you could simply use the limit method:

```
current_app_user.photos.limit(10).each { |photo| # etc... }
```

If you need to get all the photos but chunk them into blocks of 10 and you're using jQuery you could this [code](https://gist.github.com/2661361) that I created that adds a `each_slice` function to the core jQuery object. It might be useful in this situation.

Comment: getting undefined method `limit'.  also how would i append to photos with the click of a button?  Also, I am using  Rails 2.3.8.

Comment: What kind of object is `current_app_user.photos`? If it's an Array then you ***should*** have the `limit` method available.